# Most efficient way to reverse the bits in a Java byte array

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, byte, reverse

Need to reverse all the bits in a byte []. I'm doing this in two steps.

1. Reverse all the bytes in this array.
2. Reverse all the bits in each byte.

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

```
public byte[] reverse(byte [] data) {
    byte [] bytes = data.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length / 2; i++) {
        byte temp = bytes[i];
        bytes[i] = bytes[bytes.length - i - 1];
        bytes[bytes.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) (Integer.reverse(bytes[i]) >>> 24)
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

1. The flipping is used as a primitive hashing function.
2. I realized that I was flipping the bits not reversing them, this has been fixed.
3. The bitwise '&' was unnecessary and has been removed.

Comment: Why do you need to reverse even the single bits inside each byte?

Comment: idk about the bits, but shouldn't you split this into two methods? reverseBytes(byte[] data) and reverseBits(byte[] data)?

Comment: In addition your reverse operation is not reversing the order, but just flipping the byte (inverting). What do you need?

Comment: Why do you need to `& 0xFF` if you're going to cast to `byte` anyways?

Comment: If you need to _reverse_ order of bits (not inverse byte value), you can pre-calculate lookup table of 256 elements.

Comment: If you need to reverse the order of bits, you could use `Integer.reverse(bytes[i]) >>> 24`.